# Cookies handling using javascript or Express.js or node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I just want to know which one is the best way to handle the cookies?
Using Express.js? Node.js or client side javascript jquery?

I am little confuse with security perspective.

Thanks for all your help/information.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle cookies"? Elaborate.

Comment: I just want to handle the "keep me logged in" checkbox and store its state in the brwser cookies so that next time user should not be asked to signin.

Comment: I have seen cookies handling in express.js and also using javascript document.cookies. So I am little confused that which one is good and why?

Comment: Note: every client cookie (except cookies with httpOnly flag) is visible using `document.cookies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep some session id in cookie, not actual data (it's true for most cases, especially for any user-related sensitive data).

The correct approach for using cookies would be:

1. Make user input his login/password and check "keep logged in" checkbox.
2. On server side, based on inputed login and password, decide if user credentials are valid.
3. Assuming valid credentials, create some random id and store information on server side, that this given random id is related to some data (some user id, settings etc.).
4. On server side, based on value of "keep me logged in" checkbox you would then do following: if checkbox was checked, create cookie that should expire in some time in very distant future (like, say, 100 years). If checkbox wasn't checked, you set cookie to expire once browser session is over or for example in 1 hour. Keep in mind, that user can tampre with expiration date of cookies once you send them, but that's a whole different story.
5. User (client) is receiving your cookie which has that generated id in it. That cookie is sent to you by browser on every request.
6. On server side, once you get your cookie from client, check if you know that id and if it is valid. If so - retreive user data from your databse or whatver and operate on those.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed description:)

Comment: One more thing I want to ask. How I can have the track of checkbox. As when next time I will hit the page It will refresh the checkbox state?:(

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are HTTP concepts which is irrespective of the language / platform. So, Node.js is a server side platform while Express.js is a server side web application framework for Node.js and jQuery is a client side library.

From security perspective, you should not store cookie information in plain text. Also, "[you shouldn't allow client side scripts to set or read the cookie value](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)". If you are already using Express.js, then I would recommend setting & reading of cookies to be taken care by your application using Express.js and ensure you encrypt the cookie values.

Comment: "and ensure you encrypt the cookie values" - also keep in mind, that keeping your data in a cookie isn't the smartest idea, better stick to keeping some id (session id if you will) which would be the key by which you would retrieve session data on server side.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh for your valid information. Can you share or provide a simple cookies handling code or link using express.js?

I am storing the name in cookies using express.js as:

response.cookie('name', 'tobi', { domain: '.example.com', path: '/admin', secure: true });
                            response.cookie('rememberme', '1', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true });

and getting as 

logger.info("request for cookies:",request.cookie.name);

But it does not seems to work and gives me undefined:(

Comment: @WTK I completely agree with you.

Comment: @WTK do you mean I should place the specific userID in the cookies rather than the complete data in the cookies?

Comment: It should be `logger.info("request for cookies:",request.cookies.name)`, cookies plural

Comment: @AliHassan I've added my own response since it was too long for a comment. Hope it will be clear now.